# Issue with removing azure storage table through azure function within data factory

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a Data Factory pipeline which trigger simple Azure Function via HTTP.

The function is meant to just delete azure storage table, it seems it's removing the table, but then the table re-appears and is populated with some rows, I could remove it from storage explorer for example, but it could re-appear again.

Basically the Data Factory pipeline is set that durable functions are populating this azure storage table, then the data is copied via copy data block to sql database, and then a function is called via a pipeline to delete storage table as it's no longer needed.

Seems that all of the data is actually copied from storage table to sql database, as when checking the re-appearing rows in storage table I can see those data in sql. I don't have any clue what's going on. The storage tables can have quite a lot of date like 100-900k of entities.

Comment: storage explorer is not necessarily real time. you'd need to give us some more details on how you are doing those delete operations, and maybe some screen shots of your data factory